# Libgdx starting frame for non-looping animation on event

Tags: java, animation, libgdx

So with the following code

```
public void update(float dt) {
    stateTime += dt;

   if(State == 1){
       if (currentAnimation.isAnimationFinished(stateTime)){
           currentAnimation = runAnimation;
           State = 0 ;
       }
   }...
```

slash is called on click

```
public void slash() {
        currentAnimation = attackAnimation;
        stateTime = 0;
        State = 1;
}
```

The problem that I'm having is sometimes the attackanimation does not start from the first frame of the animation. What I'm trying to do is simple a sword slash animation that is called on click. The attackanimation have to always start from the very first frame of the animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to make your animation start from the first frame your **statTime** values should be at 0 when the animation is called

**animation.getKeyFrame(statTime, false);**

i can't see the problem from the code you just put, but i porpose to you to do this :

```
 public void update(float dt) {

       if(State == 1){
           stateTime += dt;
           if (currentAnimation.isAnimationFinished(stateTime)){
               currentAnimation = runAnimation;
               State = 0 ;
           }
       }...
```

so you can be sure that The statTime is only incremented when the animation is called

if it didn't work leave a comment

Good luck

Comment: Resetting statTime back to 0 on my render method fixed the problem, Thanks!